# Why are log messages from imported module not shown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, logging

I can't seem to raise the log level of a module's logger. I have a script which uses the root logger, and I want to only print its `ERROR` logs. However, the module I import, I would like to log granually on `DEBUG`.

In `mymodule.py`:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

def do_something():
    log.DEBUG("Module debug")
    log.INFO("Module info")
    log.WARNING("Module warning")
    log.ERROR("Module error")
```

and in `myscript.py`:

```
import mymodule
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)

modulelogger = logging.getLogger("mymodule")
print(modulelogger)

modulelogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print(modulelogger)

mymodule.do_something()

log.DEBUG("Script debug")
log.INFO("Script info")
log.WARNING("Script warning")
log.ERROR("Script error")
```

Output when running `myscript.py`:

```
Module error
<Logger mymodule (ERROR)>
<Logger mymodule (DEBUG)>
Error:root: script error
```

1. Why am I seeing the level of the "mymodule" as `WARNING` initially? The module defines it as `ERROR`?
2. Why am I not seeing the `INFO` and `DEBUG` logs by the "mymodule" logger after setting its level to `DEBUG`?

Comment: 1. When the level of a logger is NOTSET, it shows the level of the root logger which is default to `WARNING`. 2. There is no handler attached to `mymodule` logger to print the log out. It propagates the log to the root logger by default. The root level is now `ERROR`, so only ERROR messages from the module are shown.